# Could date palm pollen sold as a food supplement pollinate a female plant?

Tags: palm, pollination

I’m trying to obtain date palm pollen to pollinate a female date palm. However I have no access to a male date palm. I’ve seen bags of date palm pollen being sold online as a health supplement; would this be a source of viable pollen?

Comment: I edited your question to focus more on the viability of the pollen and less on where to buy it. Shopping questions are off-topic here (see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285/teaching-a-man-to-fish-garden-and-shop for more information about the policy).